# How can I display an array in MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3

Hello everyone I'm trying to display my array's values in my View but there is something wrong at my foreach loop cause there is no output in my View could you help me?

```
@model icerik.TahakkukServices.MakbuzList
@using icerik.TahakkukServices


@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Deneme";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout5.cshtml";
}


@{
    TahakkukServicesClient client = new TahakkukServicesClient();
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.UserName = "service_test";
    client.ClientCredentials.UserName.Password = "...";
    client.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.CertificateValidationMode = System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateValidationMode.None;
    MakbuzList[] liste = client.GetMakbuzListe(2);

}

 @foreach (var item in liste)
 {
     Html.Display(item.Adi);



                }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need put a `@` before your `Html.Display` to make the generated html written to the output:

Also if you need to display a strongly typed property value use the `DisplayFor` method instead:

```
@foreach (var item in liste)
{
     @Html.DisplayFor(m => item.Adi)
}
```

Here is a [quickreference](http://haacked.com/archive/2011/01/06/razor-syntax-quick-reference.aspx) about the razor syntax.

Answer (score 1):

Don't be afraid to use html markup. You can display it however you want. For example like table

```
<table>
@foreach (var item in liste)
{
     <tr>
          <td>
                @item.Adi
          </td>
     </tr>
}
</table>
```

or list

```
<ul>
@foreach (var item in liste)
{
     <li>
          @item.Adi
     </li>

}
</ul>
```